# Is a question in relation to COVID19 and space travel too open ended?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask how this pandemic is expected to affect space travel and future plans for NASA and other space agencies. Is this a good question or would it be considered offtopic as its more about a logistical response to a crisis? Kind of interested on an inside view to the precautionary measures of agencies and potential funding deficits / mission delays. It is very hard to find nonsensationalized articles at the moment and I was hoping for a horses mouth to hear things from.

Sorry for the short post I am on mobile.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure there are questions that are related to COVID-19 and space travel, but just a generic "What are the plans for the entire agency" is a bit too broad... Try to be specific.

Comment: I guess I could just ask about NASA, planned missions and impacts on other things, like whether or not they were also taking preventative measures at JPL and such. That's a bit more guided.

Comment: Things like if a specific mission is delayed, how they are managing the ISS, what extra measures the astronauts going to the ISS have to take to keep it from getting to space, all would be good questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think a workable question might be

> How effective would the lunar quarantine efforts be against COVID-19?

I've been spending the last few days trying to answer some of the unanswered [apollo-program](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apollo-program) questions.  Specifically, I spent the last few hours [answering](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43241/26446) a question about lunar quarantine.  So I'm willing to answer such a question, @MagicOctopusUrn.

Comment: I now have an answer ready, in case the question is asked.

Answer (score 0):

Specific questions like:

1. Have any launches been postponed due to...
2. Have any missions been delayed due to...
3. Is data from deep space being lost due to...

will be on-topic and likely have interesting answers. I like #3 personally.

> ...too open ended?

To avoid that, specify that you are looking for only one or two examples, not a list. *Go for it!*